# Flex PHP Service generated endpoint and gateway.php

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have recently been updating a Flex 3 project to utilise the Zend services offered in **Flash Builder 4.6 for PHP Premium**.  This is now complete and I am ready to deploy my site to the live server.

My intention is to deploy the PHP resources to one server and then have the main "flash" site on another server.  The reason for this is because I have another project that will also be accessing the same PHP resources on another server.

When using the "Create PHP Service for Flex" option on my PHP files I noticed that Flash Builder automatically generates the equivalent .as files, but it also puts in a **full URL** for the endpoint, eg:

```
_serviceControl.operations = operations;
_serviceControl.convertResultHandler = com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility.convertResultHandler;
_serviceControl.source = "serviceName";
_serviceControl.endpoint = "http://localhost/php-resources-folder/gateway.php";
```

I have looked around but I can't see any way to dynamically control this endpoint URL so it can work on both my local development site and the live deployment site.  Surely this must be possible?

I have found [this post on the Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3850560) which explains how to override the class in order to set a different endpoint URL, but surely there is a simpler way?  I refuse to believe Adobe just forgot to handle this.

---

My other question is that in all debug/export versions of my site I get a generated **gateway.php** and **amf_config.ini** file.  What are these for?  From my testing I can't see any time when they are being used, especially with the endpoint pointing directly to the resources gateway.php file.

Sorry this is quite text-heavy, any help will be greatly appreciated.